# where do one add jwt bearer to header

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-7.0

I have a .Net 7 web API that generate a JWT when a user has registered for an account.  As I understand the token needs to be added to the header in order to protect certain endpoints like this...

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt);
```

but where do I do that and is that header then used in every request if set once?

Comment: "but where do I do that" does the code you posted not work? "used in every request if set once" do you use the same HttpClient for all requests?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the following header (as you shown in your code) to every request to the API.

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Verify using a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.getfiddler.com/) that the header is present.

Then on the receiving end, you typically use the AddJwtBearer handler to handle the incoming requests with tokens.

Comment: how do I use the same httpclient for every request?

Comment: Yes, crate a new instance of HttpClient for each request.

Comment: also, https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ contains some nice helper methods for calling APIs with access tokens.